# Можно ли с помощью directive изменять содержание внутреннего элемента html страницы, а не полностью заменять элемент?

Tags: angularjs, mvc, angular, angular-directive

У меня есть элемент в html странице, выглядит он так

```
<gallerybuttons></gallerybuttons>
```

С помощью директивы я могу полностью заменить этот элемент на тот, что находится в директиве. Сам код выглядит следующим образом:

```
app.directive('gallerybuttons', function () {
return {
    scope: true,
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EAC',
    controller: 'BreedController',
    controller: 'CurGalleryTab',
    template: '\
        <div class= "ButtonBreads" >\
        <span ng-repeat="e in breedsList">\
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="{{ e }}" ng-click="CurGal.setGalTab(1, e)"> {{ e }} </button>\
        </span>\
        </div>'
}
});
```

Но он полностью заменяет элемент gallerybuttons, а я бы хотел при каждом вызове директивы заменять кодом из директивы именно внутренности . Есть ли способы это сделать?

Comment: `replace: true`?

Comment: Есть, но не помогает

Comment: я имел ввиду, что это нужно отключить

Comment: А как тогда все будет обновляться? Не помогает